# Всплывающее окно на jQuery и Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap

Верстаю пробный сайт на bootstrap, хочется поместить туда всплывающее окно при возникновении ошибок. Нашел много советов по подключению библиотек jQuery. Но так как у меня уже подключена библиотека от bootstrap не приведет ли это к ошибкам ? И сам принцип вывода сообщений не понятен для меня, могли бы знающие люди объяснить что за чем идет?

К примеру вот такой код PHP:

```
<?php

$User_Email = $_POST['User_Email'];
$User_Message = $_POST["User_Message"];
$Check_Error = '';
if (trim($User_Email) == '') {$Check_Error = 'Введите свой Email';} 
elseif (trim($User_Message) == '') {$Check_Error = 'Введите Ваше сообщение';}

if ($Check_Error != '')
{require "Check_Error_Email.php" ;
exit;
}

$subject = "=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode("Тестовое сообщение")."?=";
$Headers = "From: $User_Email\r\nReply-to: $User_Email\r\nContent-type: text\html; charset = utf-8\r\n";



mail('eliseev_denis_95@mail.ru',$subject , $User_Message , $Headers);
header('Location: /contact.php');
?>
```

Так вот, при ошибке, вызывается скрипт который направляет нас на страницу с формой ошибки, а мне хотелось бы чтобы она вызывалась прямо на странице где форма заполнения записей.

Comment: Для начала. Если нужно всплывающее окно для валидации формы то данные надо отправлять на сервер при помощи `ajax`. Скрипты `bootstrap` зависимы от `jquery`, если хотите подключить сторонние библиотеки для jquery то подключайте, то что они будут конфликтовать с bootstrap вероятность крайне мала

Comment: https://fructcode.com/ru/blog/how-to-send-html-form-with-ajax/ здесь описано как отправлять данные по аякс на сервер без перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: Arendach, спасибо за информацию